# Read file from local PC from network deployed app to InputStream

Tags: file, hadoop, networking, inputstream, local

I am attempting to read a file from a local PC via a network deployed application.  I keep receiving `FileNotFoundException`.  I am using hadoop FileSystem.  I want to send to an InputStream.

```
InputStream inputStream = null;
FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.getLocal(new Configuration());
inputStream = fileSystem.open(new Path("file:///c:/test.pdf"));
```

I have a file on my local PC at `c:/test.pdf`.

I can run this fine if I am running the app locally. However if running from network deployed app, I receive:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/c:/test.pdf does not exist

Is there a way to accomplish this?